# Get 9 random photos from a Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My associations are as follows:

Collection:

```
has_many :children, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id"
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id", optional: true
has_many :albums, dependent: :nullify
```

Album:

```
has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :collection, optional: true
```

Photo:

```
belongs_to :album
```

What I wish to achieve is to, from a collection, pull 9 random photos from ANY Album either directly within the calling Collection or in any sub Collection.

My existing method only seems to pull from albums that are direct children of the calling Collection and that's not quite the effect I am after but unsure how to adjust it.

```
  def photos_for_icon
    Photo.joins(:album).where(albums: { collection_id: self.id }).order("RANDOM()").first(9)
  end
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: `Photo.joins(:album).where(albums: { collection_id: self.id }).or( Photo.joins(:album).where(albums: { collection_id: self.children.select(:id)} )).order("RANDOM()").first(9)` should do it https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/or

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for that!  That does fill in the gaps where there are child collections.  This also only does the "select 9 random photos" from one single album. What I would like is that the photos it selects from are ALL the albums that are any level of children under that Collection. So if I run this from the very top level Collection, it could select 9 photos from ANY Album.   Does that make sense?

Comment: @engineersmnky Hmmm?  That doesn't seem to be what I'm experiencing.  It appears to be favouring the first Album inside a Collection and only selecting 9 from that single Album.  I have some Collections with many Albums and a lot of photos in each and for all 9 randomly selected to be from the same Album is highly unlikely I would think?.   Strange. - Something weird going on here as it's showing the SAME 9 photos on each refresh???  Investigating!

Comment: Oh you are looking for a recursive solution at N depth? You are going to need a recursive CTE expression or possibly adoption of a gem that provides this solution. The query I provided will return the photos for the current collection and first level down but if you need N levels down there is nothing out of the box rails for that

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, that's exactly it.  I have found this gem: https://github.com/take-five/activerecord-hierarchical_query.   Does it sound feasible to use that to find all the collections and then find the albums and photos from there?

Comment: Seems like this one https://github.com/ClosureTree/closure_tree is a bit more active and has quite a bit more traction in the community. It actually builds a separate table to track the hierarchy which would be much more efficient than a dynamic CTE. That being said I have no preference as I have never used either gem so go with what works for you.

Comment: @engineersmnky. Thanks for that.  I had already added that other gem so stuck with it for a bit.  It does appear to work.  My solution right now is like so:      collections = Collection.join_recursive do |query|
        query
            .start_with(parent_id: self.id)
            .connect_by(id: :parent_id)
    end

    collections.pluck(:id)

    Photo.joins(:album).where(albums: { collection_id: collections }).reorder("RANDOM()").first(16)

Comment: glad you got it working. Feel free to answer your own question with your solution so others can find it

Comment: @engineersmnky.  I appreciate your help.  I will most likely add an answer tomorrow.  Just updating solution so that if a Collection ONLY contains albums and not other Collections then It too needs to return some photos.